# SageMaker groundtruth - seeing time it took to complete annotation?

Tags: data-annotations, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

When I use SageMaker A2i I get timeSpentInSeconds in the object returned, which is useful as we can get stats on how long it takes for workers to complete certain tasks and plan around it. However for sagemaker groundtruth, I receive a list of objects like this;

```
{
  "datasetObjectId": "0",
  "consolidatedAnnotation": {
    "content": {
      "translation2": {
        "annotationsFromAllWorkers": [
          {
            "workerId": "private.us-east-2.ex11121331faeb5c25c",
            "annotationData": {
              "content": "{\"semantic-similarity\":{\"label\":\"New\"}}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No information on time to complete is included....is there a way to get this included?